# What is the RUN command in Dockerfile for install vuetify?

Tags: docker, npm, vuetify.js

I expected and tried to include it in Dockefile directly. Here is my whole dockerfile:

```
FROM node

# make the 'app' folder the current working directory
WORKDIR /app

# copy both 'package.json' and 'package-lock.json' (if available)
COPY package*.json ./

# install project dependencies
RUN npm install
RUN npm i --save @koumoul/vuetify-jsonschema-form
RUN npm install --save axios vue-axios

RUN npm install vuetify@1.5.8

# copy project files and folders to the current working directory (i.e. 'app' folder)
COPY . .
```

But got

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vuetify' in '/app/src/views'
```

Comment: Do you have error when building an image or running a container?

Comment: @StefanGolubović No. I don't have error.

Comment: Then, I would `exec` into container and look if everything's ok with `node_modules`/project.

Answer (score 0):

It is not good practice to install separately from package.json. You should just include it in your package.json.. But I am going to teach you a technique for testing cases like this.

You can run first the image on your own `docker run -it node bash` then do there what you want to run. You can also apply bind mount so the files that you needed are included like `docker run -it -v=$(pwd):/usr/src/app node bash`.. With this you can practice everything that you are trying to run in your Dockerfile more directly